# AS3 File.documentsDirectory doesn't exist?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Currently have an issue where I'm copying a file to File.documentsDirectory before loading it into my application but one user of the application doesn't have a local Documents directory as it's mapped to a server.

Is there any way I can get around this? Maybe I could check if the documents directory exists and then save to the desktop if so?

The file/folder that is saved needs to be easily accessible but ideally not on the Desktop as this is just asking for more issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily check if a directory or file exists with the `exists` property of a [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) object:

```
var file:File;

if(File.documentsDirectory.exists){
    file = File.documentsDirectory;
}else if(File.desktopDirectory.exists) {
    file = File.desktopDirectory;
}else {
    //let the user pick the directory with FileReference class or save in File.applicationStorageDirectory
}
```

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer although it doesn't really answer the question itself.